# ASHX and "Cannot use a leading .. to exit above the top directory"

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-2.0

I have an ASHX into which I want to load a UserControl from a folder parallel to it. When I try to use a relative path using `..`, I get the exception, `Cannot use a leading .. to exit above the top directory`. There are a lot of answers on this error here already, but this situation seems different.

Initially, during development, I loaded the control using `~/MyProject/Controls/MyControl.cs`, but in production, I found that the "`~`" was different (I can't tell why, but it's a very old, very quirky setup, so I'm used to this kind of error).

First, I tried to use a relative path, `../Controls/MyControl.cs`. This failed with the error, 'Cannot use a leading .. to exit above the top directory`.

Then, I tried building the absolute path to the file, using `Server.MapPath()`, but it seems that `LoadControl()` doesn't like absolute paths.

I'm pretty confused with the `..` error, because the entire project is in a subfolder of the webroot, so you'd have to go a couple more levels deeper to go below the webroot. It is as if a generic web handler creates its own application space. I'm clearly misunderstanding something.

My abbreviated web folder structure looks kind of like this:

```
 / (webroot) 
  + MyProject/
    + Controls/
        MyControl.ascx
        MyControl.ascx.cs
    + WebHandlers/
        MyHandler.ashx
```

...and I want to load `MyControl.ascx` into `MyHandler.ashx`.

Comment: what are your iis application roots. and why does a handler need a control

Comment: The control is already used to build a block of content for a web page. The ASHX uses the exact same content (it's used for pagination after the initial pageload), so it makes sense to simply reuse it exactly as is -- and that works fine. The application root _should_ be exactly the same for my dev environment and production.